# applying unique id's (uuid) to environment objects in a list; preserving name and random-ness

Tags: r, uuid

I have a list of environment objects (R6) with a large number of associated parameters associated with each (>50 parameters for each "individual"; i.e. sex, weight, height, etc).  The objects are stored in a list in order to loop over individuals in a model.

As part of the model, I want to add new individuals to the list periodically.  My issue is that at some point I need to index the "individuals'" numeric position within the list to populate output of the model.

My solution so far has been to assign random ID numbers to each individual at its creation, then save the "individual" object and its associated name to the list, allowing me to index the position in the list using `which()`.

for example.

```
individual1 <- newobject$new(1)
```

create unique objects at the start using the R6 constructor

```
individual2 <- newobject$new(1)      #a 2nd object

population <- tibble::lst(individual1, individual2)
```

add both objects to an initial list

at this point, `names(population) returns "individual1", "individual2"`

next, within a for loop, I want to generate new individuals and assign random names because the process which triggers this loop is variable and random.  I do not want to pull from a list of prenamed items

```
newindividuals <- 5
for(i in 1:newindividuals){

new <- newobject$new(1)            
assign(UUIDgenerate(), new)        
population <- c(population, tibble::lst(randomID))

}
```

create a new object, rename it with a random id (package uuid) and then append it to the popualtion list.

the desired end result is that the new population will return:

```
names(population)
"indiviual1" "individual2" "kneslkfk-69inf-flknsek53234-lkdfj"
```

the 2 objects alreday named in the list, AND the new random alphanumeric identifier created in the loop above.

Finally:

I'd like to index the position of the individual within the list

something like:

```
which(population == individual2)
```

returns: 2

I have tried to pipe the operation and I have tried to assign the random id within a list command

```
assign(UUIDgenerate(), new) %>% c(population, tibble::lst(.)) -> population
```

This pipe does not work because the dot cannot refer to this type of enviornment object?
Without the dot notation population appends the object, but not the name.

I have also tried to assign it without dyplr piping

```
population <- c(population, (tibble::lst(assign(UUIDgenerate(), new))))
```

this appends the object to the list but makes the name
"assign(UUIDgnereate(), new)"
which is not desireable....

as for indexing the posittion within the list, which(), match(), and Position() have proved fruitless, presumable becaes the data type is a list of environments, rather than integers.  I am hopeful that using the names stored to the list, I will be able to reference the position using a placeholder in a loop...

ie

```
for(i in population){
   do things
   Position(i)
}

will return position "3" when i = "kneslkfk-69inf-flknsek53234-lkdfj"
```

I hope this is clear enough, it is hard to produce data for testing due to the complex nature of the larger model.

but simply my aims are twofold:

1. save the random generated name of an environment object to a list
2. index the numeric position of that new object within the list.